# How to restart a crashed supervised process after a certain amount of time?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I have a simple GenServer based app that parses a webpage and plays with the data that it got from it. The code looks roughly like this:

```
def start_link do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})
end

def init(state) do
  schedule_work(1)
  {:ok, state}
end

def handle_info(:work, state) do
  // Request webpage using HTTPoisson
  // Parse data using Floki
  // Use it

  schedule_work(10 * 60) # Reschedule after 10 minutes
  {:noreply, state}
end

defp schedule_work(timeout) do
  Process.send_after(self(), :work, timeout * 1000)
end
```

Today the 3rd party site stopped delivering the correct markup for some time and the parsing failed and crashed the GenServer. Supervisor restarted it and it crashed immediatley. After `:max_restarts` the Supervisor eventually stopped the application.

I don't want simply increase the `:max_restarts`. Is there a way to tell Supervisor to attempt restarts after certain amount of time? Or should I do more error handling in my parsing code to prevent the process from crashing in the first place (I assume this would be against the "Let it crash" philosophy)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how supervisor behaviour is implemented. It doesn't support delayed restarts, so you might need to implement the custom solution yourself (highly recommended, with this you would learn a lot how to detect failures with monitors or links), or you can use https://github.com/appcues/gen_retry

Comment: You could also try https://github.com/kbrw/delayed_otp

Comment: After your suggestions I Googled a bit and found this article about implementing a custom Supervisor: https://freecontent.manning.com/little-elixir-and-otp-implementing-a-supervisor/

I used it to learn about that and implemented my custom Supervisor that does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best thing to do is to both handle errors better and crash better.

You mentioned you didn't want to simply increase the `max_restarts` option. You could alternatively lower the `max_seconds` [option](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html#supervise/2-options) which defaults to 5.

Also, you could trap [exits](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#exit/2) with `Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)` and, in case of parsing errors, exit with a specific message (e.g., `Process.exit(pid, :bad_parsing)` and use that to reschedule. This might need little changes here and there in the way you supervise things, though.